# Changing an int based on another int in Java

Tags: java, variables

Recently I was trying to automate coding for javascript when I came across a bit of a problem with some of my variables.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter x start coordinate: ");
int xCoord = scan.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter y start coordinate: ");
int yCoord = scan.nextInt();
String more = "y";
int num1 = 0 + xCoord;
int num2 = 5 + yCoord;
int num3 = 13 + xCoord;
int num4 = 10 + yCoord;
System.out.println("ctx.moveTo(" + num1 + "," + num2 + ");"
        + "\nctx.lineTo(" + num3 + "," + num4 + ")\n"
        + "Mid Point: " + num3 + "," + num4);
System.out.print("Again?: ");
more = scan.next();
while (more.equals("y"))
{
    System.out.println("Enter a direction (above, left, right): ");
    String nextDir = scan.next();
    if (nextCube.equals("right"))
    {
        xCoord += 13;
        yCoord += 5;
    }
    else if (nextDir.equals("left"))
    {
        xCoord -= 13;
        yCoord += 5;
    }
    else if (nextDir.equals("above"))
    {
        yCoord -= 18;
    }
    System.out.println("ctx.moveTo(" + num1 + "," + num2 + ");"
        + "\nctx.lineTo(" + num3 + "," + num4 + ")\n"
        + "Mid Point: " + num3 + "," + num4);
    System.out.print("Again?: ");
    more = scan.next();
}
```

I found that after asking for a direction to move towards, the xCoord and yCoord variables changes, but the "num" variables did not update along with the new values. I know there must be something wrong with my thought process as to how dependant variables work in Java, but I don't know what. Help please!

Comment: Have you used a debugger yet?

Comment: When you say "dependent variables" it sounds like you think that somehow that num1 is somehow dynamically updated when xCoord changes?

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes.  This is a beginner question based on a fundamental misconception about how variable declarations work, but it contains all the elements required to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to update "num" variables in the loop, like:

```
while (more.equals("y"))
{
    ...

    // Add below codes
    num1 = 0 + xCoord;
    num2 = 5 + yCoord;
    num3 = 13 + xCoord;
    num4 = 10 + yCoord;

    System.out.println("ctx.moveTo(" + num1 + "," + num2 + ");"
        + "\nctx.lineTo(" + num3 + "," + num4 + ")\n"
        + "Mid Point: " + num3 + "," + num4);
    System.out.print("Again?: ");
    more = scan.next();
}
```

Comment: @user2316502 Thanks a lot :-)